# IB_DESIGNABLE for UIButton Failed to render instance

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, xcode7

I create a category of `UIButton` class, use IB_DESIGNABLE. But I got an strange error `Failed to render instance of RoundedCornerButton: Rendering the view took longer than 200 ms. Your drawing code may suffer from slow performance.` I tried many suggestions on this website but still cannot fix it. please help me to find the root cause.Please see the image for more detail (RoundedCornerButton: is the category of UIButton class)

[image]

**Update**: the code for `RoundedCornerButton` class:

**.h file**

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface RoundedCornerButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable int cornerRadius;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable int borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor* borderColor;
@end
```

**.m file:**

```
  #import "RoundedCornerButton.h"

@implementation RoundedCornerButton

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:self.cornerRadius];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

}
@end
```

**I can run my project on device successful**, but I got the **Red warning** as above.(It so strange, I use Xcode 7.0)

Comment: Where is your IBDesignable specified?

Comment: It's good that you showed us the error but you also need to show us your code.

Comment: Yup, very good, I see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't play with your `layer` in `drawRect` like that. That isn't drawing! Drawing is about content.

Move that code somewhere else, such as `awakeFromNib` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` (both), and all will be well.

Here's example code:

```
@implementation RoundedCornerButton

-(void) config {
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:self.cornerRadius];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

-(void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    [self config];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self config];
}

@end
```

And you can see it works fine in IB in Xcode 7:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your support. But I still got this error on Xcode 7.0, now I updated Xcode to 7.1 the error disappear. I don't sure but it seem  the error of Xcode 7.0.

Comment: What I'm saying is still good advice, though! Trust me on this one.

Comment: Ok, I'll do as your advice, but I cannot decided your answer is the root cause or not. because it cannot clear the strange red warning on Xcode 7.0.Again, thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: Well, I can't agree. Look, I've added code and a screen shot. This works fine on Xcode 7.

Comment: OK matt, I will try again and reply ASAP